# Why navigation bar shows up after minimizing app and going back to it?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, navigationbar, android-immersive

I use this code to hide navigation bar:

```
this.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)
```

But navigation bar shows up after minimizing app and going back to it? Is it possible to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the above code in onResume() and try